# C Programming (Global Variable Functions): Something is wrong with void display output

Tags: arrays, c, function, global-variables

What is the meaning of
cls: command not found error

```
void display(char name[][31], int 
q1[],int q2[], int q3[]){
int i;
float ave;

system("cls");

printf("    Name    Quiz 1   Quiz 2   
Quiz 3    Average     Remarks\n");

for (i=0;i<MAX;i++){

    ave = avg(q1[i],q2[i],q3[i]);

    printf("%d.)%s   \t%d \t%d \t%d 
    \t%6.2f\t\t",i+1,name[i],q1[i],q2[i],q3[i],ave);

        if (ave>=75.0)
            printf("Passed. \n");
        else
            printf("Failed. \n");
 }
}
```

Comment: It means the `cls` command you are trying to execute could not be found.

Comment: `cls` is a DOS command (inherited in Windows for its DOS prompt/command line window environment) to clear the screen. Systems like Linux or macOS does not have this command. You should never use `system("cls")` (or the equally common `system("pause")`).

Comment: That you have `system("cls")` in your code without knowing what it does, indicates you have fallen into [the cargo cult programming trap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). This is a bad thing, and you need to learn how to get out of this trap.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Are you certain the question in not what `system("cls")` does, but why there was an error in trying to do it?

Comment: In what environment are you running your code? Windows?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am using codeblocks on mac os big sur.

Comment: It looks like the error is related to this syntax: scanf("%[^\n]s", name[i]);

When I changed it to scanf("%s", name[i]);

The output is fixed but will now allow input of two names with space.

Answer (score 0):

### Summary

As per [@Scott Hunter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/535275/scott-hunter)'s and [@Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude)'s comments to the question, this error indicates that some program tries to execute the command `cls`, but cannot find it. Most probably it is either `dash`, `bash`, `sh`, or other similar shell.

### Details

Your code suggests that this error is a result of trying to call `system("cls")`. But, I wasn't able to get that same message executing this function. I was only able to find that executing it produces slightly different message: `sh: 1: cls: not found`. Try to execute the following code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  system("cls");
  return 0;
}
```

in either https://www.w3schools.com/c/tryc.php?filename=demo_compiler or https://ideone.com/ (in ideone you need to select the language "C").

On the other hand, I found that executing the command `cls` directly as a shell command (not within a C file) produces exactly the message you wrote: `cls: command not found`. Compare: https://ideone.com/XVQg4f

Either way, executing `system("cls")` shouldn't work on Linux nor macOS, as per [@Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude)'s comment. It may work on Windows. If you want to clear the screen on Linux (I don't know about macOS), one way is to use the `system("clear")` call. It may not be the right way in your case, but certainly is of the simplest.

If you would like to know more about the `system` C function, I recommend reading `man 3 system` (available online for example here: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html).

Related questions:

- [system("cls"); not working in C language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40727632/systemcls-not-working-in-c-language)